# hudson CI: how to delete all jobs?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have about 100 jobs on my hudson CI, possible to mass delete them ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The easiest way, IMHO, would be to use script. Go to `http://your.hudson.url/script/`

Delete jobs by running:

```
for(j in hudson.model.Hudson.theInstance.getProjects()) {
    j.delete();
}
```

And this way gives you an option to easily use condition to filter out jobs to delete.

---

**FOR JENKINS**

Current versions (2.x):

```
for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getAllItems()) {
    j.delete()
}
```

Older versions:

```
for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getProjects()) {
    j.delete();
}
```

Comment: I got a _No such property: theInstance for class: hudson.model.Hudson_ error, did some research and ended up using `(hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll { job -> job.name =~ /my-job-pattern-.*/ }).each { to_delete ->
  println ("Deleting workspace for "+to_delete);
  to_delete.delete()
}` (where _my-job-pattern.*_ is a groovy regex)

Comment: what version of Hudson/Jenkins do you use? Just tried and `theInstance` worked fine with Hudson 2.2.0.

Comment: In recent jenkins versions this now needs to be:
`for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getAllItems()) {
    j.delete()
}`

Comment: Your posted version for jenkins ignores matrix projects. Moreover, the getProjects method is deprecated in the API.

Comment: Runs without error but does not delete any jobs in jenkins 1.558

Comment: Theinstance is a private variable, not sure why can u directly access it.

Comment: @Tim it depends on security settings, but you are right it's safer to use `getInstance`

Answer (score 15):

Just delete the job directories:

```
cd $HUDSON_HOME/jobs
rm -rf <JOB_NAME>
```

See: [Administering Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson)

Comment: Guess that makes my way seem complicated :-)

Comment: but your way works better if you are using a shared hudson :)

Answer (score 7):

You can programmatically use the [XML api](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API) (or use the JSON flavor if you prefer that):

```
http://your.hudson.url/api/xml?xpath=//job/name&wrapper=jobs
```

Returns:

```
<jobs>
    <name>firstJob</name>
    <name>secondJob</name>
    <!-- etc -->
</jobs>
```

Now iterate over the job names and do a post request to

```
 http://your.hudson.url/job/your.job.name/doDelete
```

(You can do this with any programming language you like that supports XML and HTTP)

Comment: or use wget, curl or lwp-request

Comment: it gives `403` with following message `No valid crumb was included in the request`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar manageability problems with a Hudson instance that was running 500+ build jobs - it was impractical to manually maintain that many jobs using the gui. However, you can provision jobs in Hudson remotely and programatically by using the CLI - which is supplied as a jar file **[http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+CLI]**.

```
The command to delete a job would be something like:
**java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://host:port/ delete-job jobname**

And the rest of the commands you will need are here:
**java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://host:port/** help
```

I wrapped the cli in python and created an XML file from which to hold the build configuration - then I could use this to manipulate my running instances of Hudson. This also provided the ability to 'reset' the CI instance back to a known configuration - handy if you suspect build failures were caused by manual changes in the UI or if you are using a different CI server for each environment you deploy to (ie dev, test, prod) and need to provision a new one.

This has also got me out of a few binds when badly written plugins have mangled Hudson's own XML and I've needed to rebuild my instances. Hudson is also I/O bound and for really loaded instances it is often faster to boot Hudson from scratch and populate it's configuration this way.