# Jenkins: Delete a job if job name contains

Tags: jenkins

I have gone through the solution here

[hudson CI: how to delete all jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076246/hudson-ci-how-to-delete-all-jobs)

```
for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getAllItems()) {
    j.delete()
}
```

but I am afraid to run this because I don't want to delete all jobs. Is it possible I can run it based on condition,

```
for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getAllItems()) {
    if(j.contains("demo")){
         j.delete();
        }
}
```

I don't know if contains works or not, but for sake of example, to explain my requirement in a better way.

Also, what all functions we can perform using this `j` variable.

Jenkins ver. 2.176.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement conditional statements. To delete jobs that *contains* a specific string, you can use:

```
for(j in jenkins.model.Jenkins.theInstance.getAllItems()){
    if((j.fullName).contains("demo")){
        j.delete()
    }
}
```

Note: If you had 3 jobs in your Jenkins instance named "demo", "demo1", and "example", then this script would delete "demo" AND "demo1" but not "example". To only delete "demo" use the conditional:

```
if((j.fullName).equals("demo"))
```

Lastly, you can leverage [this link](https://bateru.com/news/2011/11/code-of-the-day-groovy-print-all-methods-of-an-object/) that describes how to list the specific methods available for an object referenced in the script.